# Free Chess Mobile App with no move time restriction

Tags: chess

I'm looking for a free chess mobile app or that lets me play my friends online with no time limit on moves, so we can both install the app and play games over any period of time.

Comment: What OS should it run on? There are multiple mobile OSes (e.g. Android, Tizen, iOS, WM). Hard to suggest you something without knowing essential details :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you both have iPhones? A good option would be GamePigeon.
For Android I would say LiChess, but I don't know if they have multiplayer.